# Managed C++ Error C2664

Tags: properties, copy-constructor, managed-c++, c2664

I have this struct:

```
#pragma once

#include "Defines.h"

#ifndef _COLOR_H_
#define _COLOR_H_

namespace BSGameFramework
{
namespace Graphics
{
    ref struct Color
    {
        public:

            Color(BYTE r, BYTE g, BYTE b);
            Color(BYTE r, BYTE g, BYTE b, BYTE a);
            Color(Color% color) {};

            static property Color White
            {
                Color get()
                {
                    Color white = gcnew Color(255, 255, 255);

                    return white; // Here the error
                }
            }

        private:

            BYTE r;
            BYTE g;
            BYTE b;
            BYTE a;
    };
}
}

#endif
```

and when I'm compiling the file I'm getting this error:

> Error 1   error C2664: 'BSGameFramework::Graphics::Color::Color(const BSGameFramework::Graphics::Color %)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'BSGameFramework::Graphics::Color ^' to 'const BSGameFramework::Graphics::Color %'   c:\users\nicola\desktop\directx prove\bsgameframework\bsgame\Color.h    24  1   BSGame

*PS: `BYTE` is defined in Defines.h as `unsigned char`*

SOLVED:

I've changed the property as follow:

```
static property Color^ White
{
    Color^ get()
{
    Color ^white = gcnew Color(255, 255, 255);

    return white;
}
}
```

Comment: That it's not C++. C++, managed C++, C++/CLI, C++/CX are all different languages. Please edit the tags to remove C++ and add the right one.

Comment: Ok I'm sorry, done it!

Comment: It would help if you could mark the line of code where the error occurs.

Comment: Thanks. I mentioned C++/CLI and C++/CX because I don't think what you're using is really Managed C++ (according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235298.aspx), that didn't use `ref struct`), but I'm not sure what it *should* be tagged as. Or I could be mistaken about what Managed C++ is. :)

Comment: Thanks to you too, done it :D

Comment: The difference between value types and reference types is a very important one in .NET.  Like System::Drawing::Color, this too should be a value type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the property to:

```
static property Color^ White
{
  Color get()
  {
    Color ^white = gcnew Color(255, 255, 255);

    return white;
  }
}
```

or

```
static property Color White
{
  Color get()
  {
    return Color(255, 255, 255);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks now it's working, you have forget to change Color get() in Color^ get() too, so now I'have this

    static property Color^ White
    {
 Color^ get()
 {
     Color ^white = gcnew Color(255, 255, 255);

     return white;
 }
    }

Can you explain me what Color^ is?

Comment: I've added another example which doesn't allocate the object on the heap, as `Color` is a `struct`.

Comment: Yes perfect the second is the best way :D

Answer (score 1):

`const` doesn't make sense for managed type parameters. Change the constructor to:

```
Color(Color% color)
```